# Why is my UIVisualEffectView show in viewHierarchy but not in my device?

Tags: ios, swift

I am facing an incomprehensible problem.

I have a login UIViewController and a ProgressLoading UIVisualEffectView.
I want to print the loading when I am making an API call and waiting for response.
Here is myProgressLoading Class

```
import UIKit

class ProgressLoading: UIVisualEffectView {

    var text: String? {
        didSet {
            label.text = text
        }
    }

    let activityIndictor: UIActivityIndicatorView = UIActivityIndicatorView(activityIndicatorStyle: UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.gray)
    let label: UILabel = UILabel()
    let blurEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: .light)
    let vibrancyView: UIVisualEffectView

    init(text: String) {
        self.text = text
        self.vibrancyView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: UIVibrancyEffect(blurEffect: blurEffect))
        self.vibrancyView.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0.2, alpha: 0.7)
        super.init(effect: blurEffect)
        self.setup()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        self.text = ""
        self.vibrancyView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: UIVibrancyEffect(blurEffect: blurEffect))
        self.vibrancyView.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0.2, alpha: 0.7)
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        self.setup()
    }


    func setup() {

        contentView.addSubview(vibrancyView)
        contentView.addSubview(activityIndictor)
        contentView.addSubview(label)
        activityIndictor.startAnimating()
    }

    override func didMoveToSuperview() {
        super.didMoveToSuperview()

        if let superview = self.superview {

            let width = superview.frame.size.width / 2.3
            let height: CGFloat = 50.0
            self.frame = CGRect(x: superview.frame.size.width / 2 - width / 2,
                                y: superview.frame.height / 2 - height / 2,
                                width: width,
                                height: height)
            vibrancyView.frame = self.bounds

            let activityIndicatorSize: CGFloat = 40
            activityIndictor.frame = CGRect(x: 5,
                                            y: height / 2 - activityIndicatorSize / 2,
                                            width: activityIndicatorSize,
                                            height: activityIndicatorSize)
            activityIndictor.color = UIColor.white

            layer.cornerRadius = 8.0
            layer.masksToBounds = true
            label.text = text
            label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.center
            label.frame = CGRect(x: activityIndicatorSize + 5,
                                 y: 0,
                                 width: width - activityIndicatorSize - 15,
                                 height: height)
            label.textColor = UIColor.white
            label.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 16)
        }
    }

    func show() {
        self.isHidden = false
    }

    func hide() {
        self.isHidden = true
    }
}
```

Here is how I work with my progressLoading, a show and hide methods and declare with a text.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    progressLoading = ProgressLoading(text: "Loggin in...")
    progressLoading?.hide()
    self.view.addSubview(progressLoading!)
}



func startAnimatingLoading(viewModel: Login.ViewModel) {
    self.progressLoading?.show()
}

func stopAnimatingLoading(viewModel: Login.ViewModel) {
    self.progressLoading?.hide()
}
```

My problem is that when I wait for the response, I show the loading programatically, but nothing appears in my device. (if you wonder, I simulate long API callback by just making a breakpoint and stay on the breakpoint)

I looked inside the viewHierarchy and the Loading is right here in front of everything exactly how I want it to be.

Here is my ViewHierarchy :

[image: a busy cat]

Is there something I didn't get with the viewHierarchy ? 
How is this possible that something is shown on the view hierarchy but not inside my device ?

Thanks you for your help, I just don't get it !

Comment: show us a code of the ProgressLoading class

Comment: Yes, that makes sense. Just updated !

Comment: I'm guessing your superview has no frame when you create the ProgressLoading view (set a breakpoint to check). Set the frame later or use autolayout.

Answer (score 0):

Are you making the API call on the main thread? If you start the animation and then block the main thread the progress indicator won't appear - the system needs at least one draw cycle to actually display the indicator. Move your simulated API call to a background thread and then show your indicator before the call and hide it when API responds. Hope this helps!

Comment: I am not even calling the API right now, I'm just calling the startAnimation and making a breakpoint far later so I can see the update.
So no, it can't be because of the thread. If it was because of the thread, I wouldn't see the loadingAnimation inside the hierarchyView

Comment: What do you mean by 'far later'? If you are just adding a breakpoint in the same function or in another function that's just being called after the 'startAnimation' you are effectively just breakpointing on the main thread and then calling 'stopAnimation'. System has not had the time to actually draw anything. Try adding two buttons to your UI - one to start your animation and one to stop it. Then tap start - see what happens :)